# plupload upload directory target dir creation

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, directory, plupload

I am using Plupload with codeignitor.

My problem is i cant create new folder on the server[I am guessing this will be the problem].

Here the controller goes ...

```
    function do_upload()
    {
                    //$targetDir = ini_get("upload_tmp_dir") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "plupload";


                    $current_user = $_REQUEST['userDEMO'];

                    $c_pagename = $_REQUEST['c_page'];




                    $targetDir = "/home/username/public_html/developer/uploads/".$current_user."/";


            //$cleanupTargetDir = false; // Remove old files
            //$maxFileAge = 60 * 60; // Temp file age in seconds

            // 5 minutes execution time
            @set_time_limit(5 * 60);

            // Uncomment this one to fake upload time
            // usleep(5000);

            // Get parameters
            $chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? $_REQUEST["chunk"] : 0;
            $chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? $_REQUEST["chunks"] : 0;
            $fileName = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : '';

            // Clean the fileName for security reasons
            $fileName = preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '', $fileName);

            // Make sure the fileName is unique but only if chunking is disabled
            if ($chunks < 2 && file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName))
                {
                    $ext = strrpos($fileName, '.');
                    $fileName_a = substr($fileName, 0, $ext);
                    $fileName_b = substr($fileName, $ext);

                    $count = 1;
                    while (file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b))
                            $count++;

                    $fileName = $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b;
                }

            // Create target dir
            if (!file_exists($targetDir))
            {
                 @mkdir($targetDir,0755,true);
            }


            if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"]))
                    $contentType = $_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"];

            if (isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]))
                    $contentType = $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];

            // Handle non multipart uploads older WebKit versions didn't support multipart in HTML5
            if (strpos($contentType, "multipart") !== false)
                {
                    if (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
  // Open temp file
  $out = fopen($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName, $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
  if ($out)
                    {
   // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
   $in = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");

   if ($in) {
    while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
     fwrite($out, $buff);
   } else
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
   fclose($in);
   fclose($out);
   @unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
         }
                    else
              die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
                        }
                    else
                     die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');
                 }
             else
                 {
                // Open temp file
                $out = fopen($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName, $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
                if ($out)
                    {
                        // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
                        $in = fopen("php://input", "rb");

                        if ($in) {
                                while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                                        fwrite($out, $buff);
                        } else
                                die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');

                        fclose($in);
                        fclose($out);
                    }
                        else
                         die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
                }
                // Return JSON-RPC response
                die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}');

             }
```

I dont know what is the problem,it stuck on upload [No progress bar or anything]

hope that problems comes here

```
$targetDir = "/home/username/public_html/developer/user/".$current_user."/"."pages/pageName/images/";
```

and here

```
// Create target dir
            if (!file_exists($targetDir))
            {
                 @mkdir($targetDir,0755,true);
            }
```

**EDIT :** 
**Directory Structure :**

```
--Public_html
  -- Codeignitor_installation_files [default_one_for_showing_coming_soon_page_etc]
  -- Developer [0755]
     -- Codeignitor_default_files
     -- User [0777]
        -- Username1 [0777]
           -- Pages [0777]
              -- PageName1 [0777]
                 -- Images [0777]
                    -- img1.jpg   
              -- PageName2
        -- Username2
```

I want to upload the file to `Images` folder

**Edit :**

My controller function can create a a folder on my server if i visited the function through browser ,but its not working with PLUPLOAD,i corrected the URL settings in PLUPLOAD,but no way....

atleast is there any way to debug ? i am currently in flash runtime...so i am not able to see what is happening when i click "Upload File"

Comment: Remove the @ from @mkdir and see the error in your error log. This is mostly a permissions issue. Have you CHMODed the parent directory to 777.

Comment: @AlecSmart ahh thanks..let me check..

Comment: I checked ..but its not working..

Comment: @DileepDil, did you ever get this working?, I am having the same issue.

Comment: @Fabii i updated the configuration to html4 ..

Comment: I found it was a permissions issue for me. After putting in the proper permissions , it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not working on Flash Runtime:

I updated the runtime to HTML4 on plupload configuration,and its working !!